# How do I see what streaming accounts are already tied to my PS4?

Tags: ps4, streaming, twitch

Playstation recently updated their OS and I'm having trouble finding what broadcasting accounts (such as Twitch or YouTube) I've already added to my PS4's broadcasting settings.

Is there a new menu that allows me to see the Twitch or YouTube usernames that are currently tied to the console?

I believe there is a way through the PS4 App, but I'm looking for a menu directly on the console.

Comment: Are you talking about like Netflix/Hulu/YouTube/CrunchyRoll type subscriptions or is this specifically about streaming accounts?

Comment: @Vemonus - Specifically broadcasting accounts such as Twitch.  I'll edit the question to clarify. Thanks!

Comment: Is it in a different place than the account's linked subscriptions?

Comment: Yes, there is a "Broadcasting Settings" menu that houses streaming accounts in the "Settings" of the PS4 OS.

Comment: ah, I don't stream so I wasn't aware of a difference. Though I could've sworn the Twitch and YouTube subs were listed next to my streaming accounts like Hulu/Netflix/CrunchyRoll... will definitely take a look when I get home today and get back to you if no one else does in the meantime!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to see all accounts for services that you've linked to your PSN account. Each user on the console is able to link accounts to services as they choose, so you aren't limited to one account per console per service. However, each user can only see their own account links. To see these linked accounts, here are some directions.

From your home screen, go to your Settings:

[image: home > settings]

Then, go to "PlayStation Network/Account Management":

[image: psn/account management]

From there, go to "Link with Other Services":

[image: link with other services]

Once there, you'll see a list of a bunch of services you either have or are able to link with your PSN account. The ones you have linked are marked with a check mark:

[image: list of services]

If you click on a service that you've linked to your PSN account, it will display the account you've linked for that service. For example, YouTube will tell you the name and email of the account you've linked to your PSN account.

[image: youtube account]

Comment: You sir are a rock star!  I've confirmed this as the solution.